# How to make this type of Animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-packages

[image: Source Image]

Above the image to below the animation.
How to Extract the single part of the image element in flutter then make to below animation.

How to achieve this type of animation in flutter. It was done by CSS. I was working to make this type of animation but I need some Suggestions and Example. If you know please share your experience and knowledge for achieve this.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: You may create a gif file of this animation and may use in flutter.

Comment: As a developer we can't do that way. We should do in the coding... Thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: This may need to be build from scratch using [basic animation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations) widget in flutter. May took a-lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the SVG file of each of the gears and use the Rotation Transition Widget and stack Widget for Rotation and use AnimatedContainer for wieght